# Accessing POST json in clojure

Tags: json, post, clojure, compojure

**EDIT** - The [source code is on github](https://github.com/PhosperousGodzilla/clojurejsonapi) if you're interested. Thanks

---

I am a bit confused as to how to access json data that has been posted to a url in clojure; I just can't seem to get it to work.

This is my route:

```
(cc/POST "/add" 
request
(str ": " request))
```

I am not entirely sure what I have to put in place of `request` - I just saw some blog online and tried to follow it, but couldn't get it to work.

Here's how I'm trying to post: (from [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/))

[image: fiddler posting data]

<sup>note: request header port is different in the image; it's a mistake, I was trying to mess with that data to see what it says so ignore that part in the above image please</sup>

In curl, I'm just doing this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo":"bar","baz":5}' 
     http://localhost:3005/add
```

It looks like clojure is not receiving the json data that I posted at all.

Here's what the request var contains:

```
: {:scheme :http, :query-params {}, :form-params {}, :request-method :post, 
   :query-string nil, :route-params {}, :content-type "\"application/json\"", 
   :uri "/event", :server-name "localhost", :params {}, 
   :headers {"user-agent" "Fiddler", "content-type" "\"application/json\"", 
          "content-length" "23", "host" "localhost:3005"}, 
   :content-length 23, :server-port 3005, :character-encoding nil, :body #}
```

As you can see, all `params` are empty...

I am using compojure and cheshire - and I can convert data into json and return them just fine for `GET` routes..  I need to figure out how to pass json and convert it into clojure data..

thanks

Comment: The posted data should be `{"foo" : "bar" , "baz" : 5}` and not `'{"foo" : "bar" , "baz" : 5}'`

Comment: @Ankur, tried that, doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because :params is filled by a ring middleware which deals with "form-encoded" body.

You can use ring-json to wrap your application into this other middleware. It will parse the JSON body and fill :params accordingly. (https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json)

Comment: Hi, I was using cheshire for converting to json on response, looking at ring, I removed cheshire completely and replaced it with ring as it was mentioned on github.. now nothing works, the page just returns 0 content length (previously response was json) with not even content type set.. is there a tutorial or something anywhere that explains this from ground zero? Sorry, I'm an absolute beginner and can't find my way around clojure very well at the moment

Comment: Trouble seems to be that most of the blogs seem to be outdated and are using old code that's not present in the same namespace as ring-json.. for example:  `[ring.middleware.format-params :only [wrap-json-params]]` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150297/accessing-posted-json-with-ring-format-params-middleware

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that does what you want. The code was taken from this [project](https://github.com/drsnyder/poky). In the README you will see some of the access patterns that this supports. The code is a little messy, but it should illustrate how this can be done.

```
(ns poky.protocol.http.jdbc.text
  (:require [poky.kv.core :as kv]
    (compojure [core :refer :all]
               [route :as route]
               [handler :as handler])
    [ring.util.response :refer [response not-found]]
    (ring.middleware [format-response :as format-response ]
                     [format-params :as format-params])
    [cheshire.core :as json]
    [ring.middleware.stacktrace :as trace]))

;
; curl -d"some data" -H'Content-Type: application/text' -v -X PUT http://localhost:8080/xxx
; curl -d'{"bla":"bar"}' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -v -X PUT http://localhost:8080/bla

(def valid-key-regex #"[\d\w-_.,]+")

; FIXME: this should be split- one fn for get, one for mget
(defn- wrap-get
  [kvstore ks params headers body]
  (response 
    (let [eks (clojure.string/split ks #",")
          nks (count eks)
          multi (> nks 1)
          ret (if multi (kv/mget* kvstore eks) (kv/get* kvstore ks))]
    (condp = (get headers "accept")
      "application/json" ret
      "text/plain" (if multi (throw (Exception. "Multi get unsupported with Accept: text/plain")) (get ret ks))
      ret))))



(defn- wrap-put
  [kvstore ks params headers body]
  (if (and 
        (= (get headers "content-type") "application/json")
        (get params (keyword ks) nil))
    (kv/set* kvstore ks (get params (keyword ks)))
    (kv/set* kvstore ks body))
  (response ""))

(defn api
  [kvstore]
  (let [api-routes
        (routes
          (GET ["/:ks" :ks valid-key-regex] {{:keys [ks] :as params} :params body :body headers :headers}
               (wrap-get kvstore ks params headers body))
          (PUT ["/:ks" :ks valid-key-regex] {{:keys [ks] :as params} :params 
                                             body :body body-params :body-params headers :headers} 
               (let [body (slurp body)
                     body (if (empty? body) body-params body)]
                 (wrap-put kvstore ks params headers body))))]

    (-> (handler/api api-routes)
        (format-params/wrap-format-params
          :predicate format-params/json-request?
          :decoder #(json/parse-string % true)
          :charset format-params/get-or-guess-charset)
        (format-response/wrap-format-response
          :predicate format-response/serializable?
          :encoders [(format-response/make-encoder json/encode "application/json")
                     (format-response/make-encoder identity "text/plain")]
          :charset "utf-8")
        trace/wrap-stacktrace)))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to a previous answers, now is enough to add `formats` key with list of formats which will be processed by Ring to your handler.

So something like

```
(def app (noir.util.middleware/app-handler 
           [your-routes]
           :formats [:json-kw]))
```